# Linux kernel patching issue

Tags: linux-kernel, compiler-errors

I have some trouble getting this particular kernel patch to compile correctly with my Ubuntu Linux kernel.

The patch in question comes from a piece of software called SCST it a iSCSI target for Linux. The patch loads fine when I run `patch -p1 < put_page_callback-2.6.32.patch` but when I got to compile I get about an hour in or so and then make fails and returns these errors.

```
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:63: error: redefinition of '__kcrctab_net_get_page_callback'
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:14: note: previous definition of '__kcrctab_net_get_page_callback' was here
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:63: error: redefinition of '__kstrtab_net_get_page_callback'
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:14: note: previous definition of '__kstrtab_net_get_page_callback' was here
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:63: error: redefinition of '__ksymtab_net_get_page_callback'
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:14: note: previous definition of '__ksymtab_net_get_page_callback' was here
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:66: error: redefinition of '__kcrctab_net_put_page_callback'
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:17: note: previous definition of '__kcrctab_net_put_page_callback' was here
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:66: error: redefinition of '__kstrtab_net_put_page_callback'
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:17: note: previous definition of '__kstrtab_net_put_page_callback' was here
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:66: error: redefinition of '__ksymtab_net_put_page_callback'
/root/d1/development/kernel/lucid/source/net/ipv4/tcp_zero_copy.c:17: note: previous definition of '__ksymtab_net_put_page_callback' was here
```

and I have absolutley no idea what is going on. I am not a kernel dev by any means, I am just trying to get this patch and another one which works fine `scst_exec_req_fifo-2.6.32.patch`. So I can make this iSCSI target run at full speed.

Any idea what I can do?

** UPDATE **

I am following the insructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile. More specificly a link on that page that goes to http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/05/05/how-to-compile-a-ubuntu-lucid-kernel/.

I have already done a few compiles using these instructions, my problems were either I forgot to apply the patches or the patch did not take, but up until now they always completed. Something with this new patch messed something up.

As far as why the iSCSI target is messing with the network parts, it apperantly has something to do with the network performance. When I compile the target software without the patch it whines about the performance wont be good. The website for the target is http://scst.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: It looks like there may be a bad #define guard somewhere and its redefining some symbols. Can you show us how you build? iSCSI target shouldnt be messing with any ipv4 things which is why I'm curious. Also which linux distro are you building on? (I've had issues where people tell me my kernel doesnt build on 11.04 ubuntu correctly, still not sure why because pre compiled version boots fine)

Comment: I will write more in the question, but the basics are: Ubuntu 2.6.32-34.74 from the Ubuntu GIT repo, its based on Lucid Lynx.

Comment: Just for kicks I tried applying the patch for 2.6.33 instead, and it made it worse. My thinking in that was the other one might be a bit closer to my kernel with is much higher in minor version than the one the SCST patch for 2.6.32 was generated from. But like I said it did not work. So I use my VM snapshot to go backwards.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu/Debian kernel specific things but I would try this. Download pure linux kernel (from kernel.org), extract it. Do sudo make menuconfig and go to save .config file. Apply patch. Run sudo make, sudo make modules_install, sudo make install. cd /boot. sudo mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-2.6.32-34 2.6.23-34. and finally sudo update-grub. See if it compiles this way.

Comment: normally that would be fine, but I am compiling this kernel to replace the one on my Ubuntu "SAN" server. This method I followed ends up creating DEB packages for me.

Comment: Either way you accomplish the same thing, just copy the linux image files to /boot and run mkinitramfs, all the .deb does is package those things for you. I'm not sure but Ubuntu might just be making it more trouble.

Comment: What about the linux headers and the other parts?

Comment: When you do modules_install it installs device drivers and kernel headers

Comment: Ah I see, I will give it a try. Its the best idea I can also think of. Thanks.

Comment: If it works out I'll put it as the answer, I just didn't want to be editing it for every response as it's hard to narrow down the issues.

Comment: It works, post answer so I can give you credit. By works I mean the compile finished with appropriate modification selected. Now I need to see if it boots. I ended up using kernel.org source `2.6.39.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the standard kernel compilation method after getting yourself an appropriate kernel version from kernel.org

Here are the steps in order

1. Extract kernel to a folder
2. Apply patch
3. sudo make menuconfig, save default .config file
4. sudo make
5. sudo make modules_install
6. sudo make install
7. cd /boot
8. sudo mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-(your version here) (your version again)
9. sudo update-grub

You should now see the new kernel in your boot options and it should (hopefully) boot.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon, it does not boot at all and when I try to remake the kernel I get error when I follow the above steps. Before when I got it to compile that was using something called kpkg-make. I am lost I don't know what the heck is making this thing fail. It seems like all of the patches are shot.

Comment: can you boot a standard kernel with no patch from steps above?

Comment: see if it's the patch that is not working or if it's that the compilation process or installation of the kernel is producing a kernel that does not boot. And by does not boot I mean the kernel simply shows a black screen, not dropping to a shall or something.

Comment: When I tried it before I got a black screen with no shell. Though I did find the issue with the patch I was messing with, there was / is a bug with it. So now I was able to compile correctly so its a start.

Comment: All seems good now, I got the patch issue sorted out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So it was an issue with the patch then?

Comment: The patch was repeating the code 3 times in the .c file that throwing errors, removed redundant code, problem solved. iSCSI software runs great.